# Not receiveing output for Indexed Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, echo

The output I am trying to receive is 

`"The Interest Rates are:
0.0525 
0.0550 
0.0575"`

This will continue to `$InterestRate7` value. I tried to link the new array elements with the old interest rate `($InterestRate1 = 0.0525; $RatesArray[1] = $InterestRate1)`    but it still does not work for me.Here is my code for extra help.

```
<?php
$InterestRate1 = 0.0525;
$InterestRate2 = 0.0550;
$InterestRate3 = 0.0575;
$InterestRate4 = 0.0600;
$InterestRate5 = 0.0625;
$InterestRate6 = 0.0650;
$InterestRate7 = 0.0700;
$RatesArray = array(
$RatesArray[1] = "0.0525";
$RatesArray[2] = "0.0550";
$RatesArray[3] = "0.0575";
$RatesArray[4] = "0.0600";
$RatesArray[5] = "0.0625";
$RatesArray[6] = "0.0650";
$RatesArray[7] = "0.0700";);
echo $RatesArray[1];
?>
```

Comment: Please, read a manual how to create array values

Comment: Well I would say you are probably getting some errors so you might want to resolve those.

Comment: Try this [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/204/arrays/768/initializing-an-array#t=201701280111048279883)

Answer (score 0):

The array() construct doesn't work quite like what you have here. Try something similar to the example in the php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

```
$RatesArray = array(
1 => "0.0525",
2 => "0.0550",
3 => "0.0575");
```